# Control the distribution of job or task in Spark cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I setup a cluster which consists of `1 master and 3 workers`.

In normal condition, as we know, if users submit some jobs and jobs will be distributed to three workers for execution.

However, if I want to assign such as

`job id_1` to `worker 1` and `worker 2`, but no `worker 3`

`job id_2` to `worker 1`, `worker 2` and `worker 3`

`job id_3` to `worker 2` and `worker 3`, but no `worker 1`

Can Spark do this through some configuration setting, scheduling or write code to assign the job to workers which are specified?

Any idea or method can be recommended.

Comment: Having to specify the workers nodes kind of defeats the purpose of  fault tolerance

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this because it will make your job slow will create unwanted problems .[image]

1. Set location preference! If you know all the names of the worker 
   machines, you can created with a version of parallelize where you can 
   set the preferred location of each partition. That will ensure a 
   deterministic behavior of sending each partition to corresponding 
   worker (assuming speculative execution, and delay scheduling is turned 
   off).
2. To figure out the name of the worker nodes without hardcoding, you 
   could run a dummy Spark job with many many partitions which will 
   return the hostname of all the workers. Not that will try to ensure 
   (but not guarantee) at least one partition will be scheduled on each 
   active worker. In fact, if there are other jobs running in the system, 
   then probably these dummy tasks will not get scheduled on all the 
   workers. Hard to get around this without some outside mechanism to 
   know all the workers in the cluster.

I have never tried this thing the way you are trying to submit the job.

Might be this is a possible solution hint for your question[Spark Reply](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Forcing-spark-to-send-exactly-one-element-to-each-worker-node-td5605.html)

Go through the [Cluster Mode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html#cluster-mode-overview)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I know all the names of workers, can you explain in details how to set location preference?